# Count No of distinct Binary search trees formed

Tags: combinatorics

How many possible distinct binary search trees can be formed with n nodes?(Nodes are numbered from 1 to and it's not necessary that all nodes must be used)

My approach I've counted for N=1 and ans=1

For N=2 answer is 4 since {1},{2} and{1,2} and {2,1} are the possible bst's.
Similarly for N=3 ans is 14 and for N=4 ans is 50. I can't derive a general formula for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mathematical formula shall be:

```
summation ( C(n,i) * Catalan(i) ) {i = 1 to n}

Where C(n,i) = n! / ( i! * (n-i)! )
```

You can choose `i` nodes out of a possible `n` nodes in `C(n,i)` ways. After choosing those `i` nodes, form the BSTs in `Catalan(i)` number of ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think the recurrence is
$$T(n) = nT(n-1) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T(k)T(n-1-k)$$ where the first term represents the possibility not to use all nodes (times $n$ ways to choose what to omit) and the sum represents the number of possible divisions to left and right subtrees.